# How to label data with the real value in pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

Taking this example from PGFplot gallery.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
x tick label style={ /pgf/number format/1000 sep=}, 
ylabel=Population, 
enlargelimits=0.15, 
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
anchor=north,legend columns=-1}, 
ybar=5pt,% configures `bar shift' bar width=9pt,
nodes near coords, 
point meta=y *10^-7 % the displayed number ] 
\addplot coordinates {(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6) (1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)}; 
\addplot coordinates {(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6) (1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)}; 
\legend{Far,Near} 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The resulting graph is this:

[image]

I would like to have the whole value printed next to the bars. For example : instead of 5 I would like 5*10^7.

Comment: The line `point meta=y *10^-7` scales the numbers by dividing by `10 000 000`. Remove that line, and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: In general I should use `point meta=y ` in order to have the whole value printed ?

Comment: `point meta=y` is the default, so you can just omit that line

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is most likely solved in the comments below the question.

Comment: I would prefer if @Jake could make an answer from his comments.